# Using bash and expect

Tags: bash, expect

I'm using expect script to automate install rpm remotely. So I'm having some troubles with variables bash into expect. For example, I want to get hostname of host and set into variable, after I will use this variable in sed.

Follow the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 15

set operador "operador"

set password_operador "a123456"
set password_root "123456a"

set Zabbix_IP "10.1.10.10"
#set Zabbix_IP [exec hostname -I]
#set Zabbix_IP [exec hostname -I\|cut \-f1 \-d' ']

set f [open "hosts"]
        set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach host $hosts {
        if { ! ( $host == "" ) } {    
                spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $operador@$host
                expect "password: "
                send "$password_operador\r"

                expect "$ "
                send "su -\r"

                expect ": "
                send "$password_root\r"
                send "rpm -iv /home/operador/Zabbix_Packages_Configs/zabbix-agent2-5.0.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm \r"
                send "sleep 1 \r"

                expect "# "
                send "V_HostNameZabbix=$(hostname)_SRV \r"
                send "V_MetaData=TimBR_Linux_SRV_SPO \r"
                send "sed -i \"s/^Server=127.0.0.1/Server=$Zabbix_IP/g\" /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.conf \r"
                send "sed -i \"s/^ServerActive=127.0.0.1/ServerActive=$Zabbix_IP/g\" /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.conf \r"
                send "sed -i \"s/^Hostname=Zabbix server/Hostname=$V_HostNameZabbix/g\" /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.conf \r"

                expect "# "
                send "exit\r"

                expect "$ "
                send "exit\r"
        }
}
```

But I'm receiving the error: "can't read "(hostname)": no such variable" but hostname is system variable in CentOS 7.

How can I fix it?

---

I identify what I'm doing wrong. First I escape '$' like said by Glenn (thanks for that). So I need to set in the code the variables NULL or Empty.

```
# setting null var
set V_HostNameZabbix ""
set V_MetaData ""
```

Change these lines:

```
        send "V_HostNameZabbix=$(hostname)_SRV \r"
        send "sed -i \"s/^Hostname=Zabbix server/Hostname=\$V_HostNameZabbix/g\" /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.conf \r"
```

### Now scripts runs correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Expect uses Tcl. If you prefer shell  you can try my [Expect for Shells](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/).

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming from expect.
All you need to do is protect the dollar sign from expect's expansions so that it gets sent to the remove host:

```
send "V_HostNameZabbix=\$(hostname)_SRV \r"
# .....................^
```

Tcl (expect is a Tcl extension) has an associative array data structure, and elements are referenced with `$array(key)` syntax. The array name is allowed to be empty, so `$(hostname)` is valid Tcl syntax to get the value of the "hostname" key in the array named "". But there's no such array defined: that's the "no such variable" error.

Comment: HI @glenn-jackman, I'm already tried it before and receive error too like: " can't read "V_HostNameZabbix": no such variable"

Comment: I get it what I'm doing wrong and not just it. Thanks.